# Is there any jvm use Tri-color Marking Algorithm to marking reachable object?

Tags: java, algorithm, garbage-collection, jvm

Some articles indicated that OpenJDK/Oracle 1.6/1.7/1.8 JVMs default to following card marking logic. (http://psy-lob-saw.blogspot.hk/2014/10/the-jvm-write-barrier-card-marking.html)
But in wiki [Tracing garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_garbage_collection#Tri-color_marking), it claim that tri-color algorithm also have great performance.

I am so confused that is there any jvm use Tri-color Marking Algorithm? In other words, compare with Card Marking Algorithm, where are the advantages of Tri-color Marking?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the card marking algorithm and the tri-color algorithm are used for different purposes:
Card Marking is used for Keeping track of References from the tenured generation to young generation.
Tri-color algorithm is used for finding out which objects are reachable from the set of roots. Tri-color algorithm uses the set of objects identified by the card marking algorithm as GC Roots.

Answer (score 1):

The card marking isn't for individual objects; it's for sets of objects at a time. Basically, it's to track inter-region references. If you have memory in areas A, B, C and all the objects in A are self-contained, all the objects in B are self-contained, and all the objects in C are self-contained, then you don't have any cards marked. As a result, when it comes to garbage collect A, you don't need to consider any objects from B or C to know if objects in A are reachable - and thus, you can clean them out locally.

What card marking does is therefore optimise the amount of memory you need to scan when performing a garbage collection.

When you have an object in B referring to an object in A, the card table gets marked to indicate that there's a cross-region reference. As a result, when garbage collecting A it also needs to traverse B (or more precisely; the sub-set of B that has been card marked to refer to out-of-region objects) to determine whether or not the object in B is still alive. So it moves the problem of an incremental GC from 'all objects' to 'all objects in A and B'. In this case, C doesn't get processed at all.

These marking techniques are applicable to sets of objects; they don't deal with individual object retention. So as well as card marking, the objects also have mark flags (which are in the mark word of every instance) that contain whether or not the object has been marked/swept/whatever the GC algorithm is. Various bits in this flag are used for this purpose, including special-case ones to indicate whether an object has been marked or not and bits that are specific to the CMS collector in the [mark word implementation](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/oops/markOop.hpp). However these details can change from release to release and will differ depending on the type of GC in use.

In any case, the point here is that card marking is for representing sets-of-objects-pointing-outside-region, and that the way instances are marked uses a different technique that is specific to the GC in use. It's not a case of one-or-the-other.